# babel src --out-file / requiring modules from src/lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Whenever I run this command `babel src --out-file client.min.js` I get a output similar to:

`var _example = require('./lib/example');
var _example2 = _interopRequireDefault(_example);`

I'm expecting the output file to compile all required project files from src to a single file to remove the require code. Any ideas?

Comment: Babel is not a bundler. You need webpack, parcel, browserify or one of the many other bundlers for that.

Comment: @connexo It's compiling my code into a single bundle though. I can see the file from './lib/example' under var Example = function () { ... }